# Stuck thread in update statement: cancelling or closing the statement, and interrupt the thread does not work

Tags: java, multithreading

I've been reading a lot about stopping threads, but I have not been able to find a solution to my issue:

I've got a Sybase DB connection with 3 threads connected.
Plus one thread to monitor those 3 threads.

However, because the server is overloaded (I know: I should fix that, but we have no money for it yet), the call to:
Statement stmt.executeUpdate("update something from some_table");
never returns.

Here's what the thread roughly does (not compilable, as it's not reproducible anyway):

```
class runQuery implements Runnable {
    public Connection conn;
    public long lastQueryRunTime = 0;
    public Statement stmt;
    public volatile keepongoing = true;

    runQuery(Connection conn, String Probe, String Server, int thisthread) {
         this.conn = conn;
         Class.forName("com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybDriver");
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sybase:Tds:"+Server+":4100?SERVICENAME="+Probe,"login","password");
    }

    public void run () {
        while(keepongoing) {
        query = "update something from some_table";
        lastQueryRunTime = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.setQueryTimeout(4);
        int result = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
        lastQueryRunTime = 0;
    }
}
```

That should give a rough idea.
On a side, I've got a "MonitorThemAll" thread that checks lastQueryRunTime: if it's too long, I want to ... do something !

So, from the monitoring thread, I've tried:
changing the keepongoing flag ... but since the thread is stuck in the update query, it does not do much
Then:
stmt.cancel(), stmt.close() => it does not seem do to much. doing a kill -3 shows that the thread is still stuck on the executeUpdate line.

I moved to more forceful solutions:
conn.close()  => from there, I get exceptions "JZ0C0: Connection is already closed" everytime I try a stmt.cancel/close (those exceptions are thrown by the stmt.cancel/close commands: ie: they are in the MonitorThemAll thread, not in the runQuery thread...)
and also:
mythread.interrupt()  => still stuck in the update query after that !

I'm running out of solutions found here and on google...
Since thread.close() is deprecated (and even though, I'd like to avoid, so that I could recover the resources engaged), I don't know what else I can try...

Would anyone have any idea of things to try ?

Comment: Don't you want to execute conn.commit() after update? I think you have classic database deadlock issue.

Comment: have you tried to print if the thread just continue running (i.e. multiple updates are still going), or it is just stuck in executeUpdate?

Comment: Can you clarify what it is you're trying to do? If the database is taking a long time to respond .. you want to ... what?

Comment: the executeUpdate actually NEVER returns... "normal" timeouts are handled properly by "stmt.setQueryTimeout(4);" (which timeouts after 4sec, in which case I catch the exception, and re-add the query in the bucket)

Comment: about the commit: it's a Sybase/Netcool DB, so there is no commit needed.

Comment: You have some crazy stuff going on with your connection code there, but ignoring that, what happens when you execute your update directly in a SQL client? Also, it would be helpful if, when your query is blocked (in Java code), you run a sp_lock, to see whats blocking execution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your problems is that the sql queries are too long to be executed, you could pass the sql query to a background thread to do the query and get the result when the query is finished (either via a callback listener or a queue).

Comment: actually, the query NEVER returns ... it's just stuck there forever.
the "normal timeouts" are already handlded by "stmt.setQueryTimeout(4);" which throws an exception, which I handle

Comment: Also, what I want to achieve, in the end:
the thread is stuck in executeUpdate "forever" => I need a way to exit this executeUpdate and move on (that's the most gracious way, but the usual cancel/close do not work) ... or somehow make the thread stop, or kill the thread or whatever is needed (from gracious exit to atrocious kill)

Comment: You can not kill a thread in Java.Only try to interrupt it and it will stop if behaves properly.So you need to investigate why the query never returns and solve that.The first thing that comes to mind is that the table is locked and that is why the query does not return.Try to verify this

Comment: Well, I've tried interrupting it, and that does nothing (the Statement probably does not implement interruptibleChannel)
and yes: I know that the problem comes from the DB: it only comes when the server is way way overloaded. Also, when the table is locked, the "stmt.setQueryTimeout(4);" triggers and I handle that properly already. The issue comes from the fact that one threads is locked for some reason, and I need to find a way to unlock it, on Java side

Comment: Are you saying that with `stmt.setQueryTimeout` although the table is locked you get the exception and the thread continues?If this is the case then why do you say that the query never returns?

Comment: because "normal" timeouts are properly handled.
but sometimes, executeUpdate never returns, and the timeout is not triggered, so the thread is stuck in executeUpdate